# Checking if object is in array with generic method

Tags: java, arrays, generics

In “Java the Complete Reference” by Herbert Schildt (10th edition), in chapter 14 on Generics there is the following example of a generic method that checks if an object is in an array:

```
class GenMethDemo {

    static <T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y) {
        . . .
    }

    . . .
}
```

I don’t understand why `V extends T` is used here.

Why do we allow array’s type to be the *sub*class of the object that we check for membership? Shouldn’t it be the other way around?

Answer (score 2):

In this case `V` needs to be a subclass of `T` as you want to call `Comparable` methods on the `V[]`. If you would allow `V` to be a super type of `T` (e.g. an Object[]) you can not call `compareTo` as these methods are not implemented.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Aren’t we restricting outselves a little? In a sense that we won’t be able to use this method to check if a subclass object is in an array of superclass objects?

Comment: But why the second type parameter is needed at all? Why not simply `T[] y`?

Answer (score 2):

After some tinkering, I am able to answer my question.

Indeed, as @m-le-rutte has stated, `V` needs to extend `T` to ensure that they both implement `Comparable<T>`. However, this is somewhat illogical, as it allows us to check superclass objects for membership in subclass arrays, but not the opposite.

Here’s how to reverse the situation:

```
public class GenMethDemo {
    static <V extends Comparable<V>, T extends V> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y) {
        . . .
    }

    . . .
}
```

As I have found out, the order of type parameters needs not to be the same as the order of method parameters.

Whether you can create a single declaration that allows both `T extends V` and `V extends T` as long as they both implement `Comparable<>` of the senior one, I do not know, but doubt.

**ADDITION**:

As @lexicore mentions, the following seems to work as well:

```
public class GenMethDemo {
    static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isIn(T x, T[] y) {
        . . .
    }

    . . .
}
```

And it too supports `x` being a subtype of `y[]`.